# elif branch taken when it should not

Tags: python

This is code for a background job doing some sort of dyndns. Picking IP address from router, checking if it was changed and if so updating routing table in domain provider.

I observe the log file writes in the elif branch on the screen (unexpectedly) while a debug print does not show.

The code (fragment):

```
# Get external IP from ASUS router
print('Getting started with main loop.')
ip_last = '1.2.3.4'

logfile= "/home/gottsch/python/hover_api.log"
with open(logfile, "a") as lf:
    lf.write(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " Starting hover_api.py : " + "\n")
    lf.write(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " WAN IP= " + str(ip_last) + "\n")

time.sleep(1.0)
last_day = datetime.datetime.now().day - 1

while True:
    ip_now = get_asus_wan_ip()
    if (ip_now == ip_last):
        print('In IF : IP from proc= ',ip_now,' == IP last= ',ip_last)
        day = datetime.datetime.now().day
        if day != last_day:
            last_day = day
            with open(logfile, "a") as lf:
                lf.write(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " WAN IP still the same " + str(ip_last) +"\n")
    elif (ip_now == '1.1.1.1'):
        print('In ELIF : IP from proc= ',ip_now,' == IP last= ',ip_last)
        with open(logfile, "a") as lf:
            lf.write(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " Telnet to ASUS router failed. Not setting IP on Hover.\n")
    else:
        # We need to do something
        print('In ELSE : WAN IP changed from ' + str(ip_last) + " to " + str(ip_now))
        with open(logfile, "a") as lf:
            lf.write(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + " WAN IP changed from " + str(ip_last) + " to " + str(ip_now) + "\n")
        ip_last= ip_now
```

Notice the elif part. The IP 1.1.1.1 is something I hacked into the proc that pulls the address from the router in case the login failed. It serves as a hint that something went wrong and some message should be printed about it.

The elif branch however is never entered. But the log file still shows the error.

From the (debug) prints to the terminal (Notice the elif part is not triggered):

```
gottsch@rpi4b:~/python $ ./hover_api_v1.2.py
Getting started with main loop.
Gets WAN IP from ASUS router.
Telnet to router started.
Telnet login on ASUS router succeeded.
In ELSE : WAN IP changed from 1.2.3.4 to 73.70.10.245
Testing: *.skywatcher.space
Hover-IP for *.skywatcher.space = 73.70.10.245
Hover-IP for *.skywatcher.space = 73.70.10.245 same as Current IP = 73.70.10.245. No action.
Testing: @.skywatcher.space
Hover-IP for @.skywatcher.space = 73.70.10.245
Hover-IP for @.skywatcher.space = 73.70.10.245 same as Current IP = 73.70.10.245. No action.
Gets WAN IP from ASUS router.
Telnet to router started.
Telnet login on ASUS router succeeded.
In IF : IP from proc=  73.70.10.245  == IP last=  73.70.10.245
Gets WAN IP from ASUS router.
Telnet to router started.
Telnet login on ASUS router succeeded.
In IF : IP from proc=  73.70.10.245  == IP last=  73.70.10.245
Gets WAN IP from ASUS router.
Telnet to router started.
Telnet login on ASUS router succeeded.
In IF : IP from proc=  73.70.10.245  == IP last=  73.70.10.245
Gets WAN IP from ASUS router.
Telnet to router started.
Telnet login on ASUS router succeeded.
In IF : IP from proc=  73.70.10.245  == IP last=  73.70.10.245
```

From the (tail -f) logfile:

```
2022-03-18 17:33:54 Starting hover_api.py : 
2022-03-18 17:33:54 WAN IP= 1.2.3.4
2022-03-18 17:33:55 WAN IP changed from 1.2.3.4 to 73.70.10.245
2022-03-18 17:33:57 Hover-IP for *.skywatcher.space = 73.70.10.245 same as Current IP = 73.70.10.245. No action.
2022-03-18 17:33:57 Hover-IP for @.skywatcher.space = 73.70.10.245 same as Current IP = 73.70.10.245. No action.
2022-03-18 17:34:22 Telnet to ASUS router failed. Not setting IP on Hover
2022-03-18 17:34:57 WAN IP still the same 73.70.10.245
2022-03-18 17:35:22 Telnet to ASUS router failed. Not setting IP on Hover
2022-03-18 17:36:23 Telnet to ASUS router failed. Not setting IP on Hover
2022-03-18 17:37:23 Telnet to ASUS router failed. Not setting IP on Hover
2022-03-18 17:38:23 Telnet to ASUS router failed. Not setting IP on Hover
```

What is triggering the fail message?  I must be making some stupid mistake, but can't find the solution.

Adding clarification as it was asked in a comment:

The log says there is failure, but the piece of code where that gets triggered has a print to console that never shows. That's the gap.

Comment: You're not seeing the print statement in the log file because print statements don't go into the log file.  Is there any reason that the ip can't be 1.1.1.1?

Comment: Based on the information you shared, it shouldn't be possible but obviously it's happening so why don't you use an IDE like PyCharm, put a break point inside the ELIF code. That could help you figure out how that is possible. If you don't want to use an IDE, you can also put `pdb.set_trace()` inside ELIF and trigger the debugger (read this for more info: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html)